# ActivityRecognitionService (Google API) is not working properly

Tags: android, api, google-api

I have developed my application using this tutorial:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-recognize-user-activity-with-activity-recognition--cms-25851

Even though I request updates every 3 seconds (or for a change, 5 seconds, 10 seconds etc); the timing of the generated values is highly inconsistent. At times it would generate 4 values in 10 minutes! Why is the API being so inconsistent? Also, I'm unable to disconnect the API, even after I call API.disconnect(), I still keep getting values in logcat, which heats up the phone and consumes battery excessively.

Here is the full project: https://github.com/AseedUsmani/MotionAnalyser2

Basic Code:

**1) Activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_analysing);
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
   mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
   mFinishButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finishButton);
   mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //resetting counter 
             for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    mCount[j] = 0;
                }
                mServiceCount = 0;
                mApiClient.connect();
                mStartButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mFinishButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        }
   mFinishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mApiClient.disconnect();
}
}
}
@Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityRecognizedService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                 ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(mApiClient, 3000, pendingIntent);
    }


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(AnalysingActivity.this, "Connection to Google Services suspended!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(AnalysingActivity.this, "Connection to Google Services failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

**2) Service:**

```
public class ActivityRecognizedService extends IntentService {

AnalysingActivity mObject = new AnalysingActivity();
int confidence;


public ActivityRecognizedService() {
    super("ActivityRecognizedService");
}

public ActivityRecognizedService(String name) {
    super(name);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
        ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
        handleDetectedActivities(result.getProbableActivities());
    }
}

private void handleDetectedActivities(List<DetectedActivity> probableActivities) {
    confidence = mObject.confidence;
    mObject.mServiceCount++;

    for (DetectedActivity activity : probableActivities) {
        switch (activity.getType()) {
            case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE: {
                if (activity.getConfidence() >= confidence) {
                    mObject.mCount[0]++;
                }
                mObject.mActivity[0] = "In Vehicle: " + Integer.toString(activity.getConfidence()) + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[0]);
                Log.e("ActivityRecogition", "In Vehicle: " + activity.getConfidence() + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[0]));
                break;
            }
            case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE: {
                if (activity.getConfidence() >= confidence) {
                    mObject.mCount[1]++;
                }
                mObject.mActivity[1] = "Cycling: " + Integer.toString(activity.getConfidence()) + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[1]);
                Log.e("ActivityRecogition", "Cycling: " + activity.getConfidence() + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[1]));
                break;
            }
            case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT: {
                if (activity.getConfidence() >= confidence) {
                    mObject.mCount[2]++;
                }
                mObject.mActivity[2] = "On Foot: " + Integer.toString(activity.getConfidence()) + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[2]);
                Log.e("ActivityRecogition", "On foot: " + activity.getConfidence() + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[2]));
                break;
            }
            case DetectedActivity.RUNNING: {
                if (activity.getConfidence() >= confidence) {
                    mObject.mCount[3]++;
                }
                mObject.mActivity[3] = "Running: " + Integer.toString(activity.getConfidence()) + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[3]);
                Log.e("ActivityRecogition", "Running: " + activity.getConfidence() + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[3]));
                break;
            }
            case DetectedActivity.STILL: {
                if (activity.getConfidence() >= confidence) {
                    mObject.mCount[4]++;
                }
                mObject.mActivity[4] = "Still: " + Integer.toString(activity.getConfidence()) + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[4]);
                Log.e("ActivityRecogition", "Still: " + activity.getConfidence() + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[4]));
                break;
            }

            case DetectedActivity.WALKING: {
                if (activity.getConfidence() >= confidence) {
                    mObject.mCount[5]++;
                }
                mObject.mActivity[5] = "Walking: " + Integer.toString(activity.getConfidence()) + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[5]);
                Log.e("ActivityRecogition", "Walking: " + activity.getConfidence() + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[5]));
                break;
            }

            case DetectedActivity.TILTING: {
                if (activity.getConfidence() >= confidence) {
                    mObject.mCount[6]++;
                }
                mObject.mActivity[6] = "Tilting: " + Integer.toString(activity.getConfidence()) + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[6]);
                Log.e("ActivityRecogition", "Tilting: " + activity.getConfidence() + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[6]));
                break;
            }

            case DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN: {
                if (activity.getConfidence() >= confidence) {
                    mObject.mCount[7]++;
                }
                mObject.mActivity[7] = "Unknown: " + Integer.toString(activity.getConfidence()) + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[7]);
                Log.e("ActivityRecogition", "Unknown: " + activity.getConfidence() + " " + Integer.toString(mObject.mCount[7]));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [requestActivityUpdates() documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi.html#public-methods):

> Activities may be received more frequently than the detectionIntervalMillis parameter if another application has also requested activity updates at a faster rate. It may also receive updates faster when the activity detection service receives a signal that the current activity may change, such as if the device has been still for a long period of time and is then unplugged from a phone charger.
>
> Activities may arrive several seconds after the requested detectionIntervalMillis if the activity detection service requires more samples to make a more accurate prediction.

And

> Beginning in API 21, activities may be received less frequently than the detectionIntervalMillis parameter if the device is in power save mode and the screen is off.

Therefore you should not expect calls exactly every 3 seconds, but assume that each call you get is the start of a state change - if you haven't received any callback, it is because nothing has changed.

Also note that the correct call to stop receiving updates is [removeActivityUpdates()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi.html#public-methods), passing in the same `PendingIntent` as you passed into `requestActivityUpdates()`.

Comment: What is exactly meant by start of state change? Like going from walking to driving? Is there anyway to make the API more consistent?

Comment: Yes, until you receive a callback, the activity and confidence is not changing. You'll only receive a callback when they change.

Comment: But I am not getting calls even if I completely change the activity, like from walking to driving or to still. Earlier I was getting values more consistently even my phone was kept still, I'd get Still with 100 confidence. Is it something to do with this message in logcat- "W/art: Suspending all threads ... " . Isbit something to do with runnable object / handler that I am using?

Comment: Maybe try something simplier. Your current code is over engineered, uses static variables wrong, does postDelayed with a delay of 0, and probably doesn't even need the Service at all (a BroadcastReceiver in your Activity would be a lot simplier). The API works as documented.

Comment: I want to display the data on the screen, and also count the number of times a particular activity is recognized. How can I do that without using static variables?
Also, I had to put a timer so I had to use multithreading, I had to access GPS location and also save the data in a file when required, hence over engineered may be.

Basically I have to work on an App which detects when the user has parked his car, so I tried detecting driving and the walking.

Thanks for your help.